# Telegram bot Python, how to send message to certain users when another event triggered

Tags: python, bots, telegram, infinite-loop, python-telegram-bot

I already have a script which checks my gmail inbox and twits the certain mails at certain intervals, for this i use a `while True` loop to have it run infinitely.

When i want to apply the same thing into a Telegram bot:

`bot.polling()` takes precedence over `while True` loop, or the the other way around. How to keep my `while True` loop running in a Telegram bot while the other functions of the bot without being interrupted?

Comment: Hey. I have a *vague* idea, where this is going, but I'll need more details about how your bot is set up and which packages you are using. E.g., I have the strong impression that you're not using the `python-telegram-library` that you tagged. Please have a look at the [SO guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking good questions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer came in as yet, however i found a transient solution. I've made use of threading library and put the '''bot.polling()''' into o function and called this function in a thread. Basically, multithreading has resolved my issue.